# iOS - String error

Tags: ios, string, geolocation

i've a piece of code that should get the current location and than put lat and long in a string.

when a new location is found i put it in a NSString

```
currentLatit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
currentLongit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
```

Than when i press a button i do:

```
NSLog(currentLatit);

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%@,%@&daddr=%@,%@",currentLatit,currentLongit,detailLatitudine,detailLongitudine]]];
```

but when i execute this, i get this error:

```
-[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e1830
2011-11-15 11:29:07.567 Marcovaldo[771:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e1830'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x30ae78bf 0x37c8c1e5 0x30aeaacb 0x30ae9945 0x30a44680 0x30a310a9 0x30ac5a97 0x30a42217 0x30a55b8f 0x37b09b9b 0x37b09b3b 0x7253 0x30a41435 0x32a9c9eb 0x32a9c9a7 0x32a9c985 0x32a9c6f5 0x32a9c321 0x32a8f99b 0x30abbb4b 0x30ab9d87 0x30aba0e1 0x30a3d4dd 0x30a3d3a5 0x3366bfed 0x32aaf743 0x2221 0x21e0)
terminate called throwing an exception(gdb)
```

The error occur on the NSLog execution

realy cannot understand what's wrong whit this simple code...

thanks for any help

-UPDATE-

changed the NSLog as follow:

```
    NSLog(@"%@",currentLatit);
```

Now the app crash with BAD_ACCESS_EXCEPTION on the NSLog

Comment: Did you mean `NSLog(@"%@", currentLatit);` ?

Comment: thanks for the hint, i've updated the code with your suggestion, now it give me a BAD_ACCESS_EXEPTION at the same point

Comment: As Gomathi suggested, try adding NSZombieEnabled to your environment variables. Also try NSLog'ing newLocation to make sure its not null by any chance.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it seems the app crashed at some point other than NSLog. Please clean and build. Or Enable [NSZombie](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/debugging/tracking-down-exc_bad_access-errors-with-nszombieenabled.html) and get the exact error location.

Update:

Just do like as following and try.

```
if( currentLatit )
  [currentLatit release];
if( currentLongit )
  [currentLongit release];
currentLatit = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude] retain];
currentLongit = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude] retain];
```